# How to get Emacs to display file in browser instead of emacs itself

Tags: org-mode

Consider the following link I have in my org-mode file

> [[file:./helloworld.py][LinkToFile]]

Emacs always opens source code files inside emacs. Web-links on the other hand are always opened in the browser. How can I get such source code files to be displayed in the browser instead?

Comment: Do you want to open all file links in a browser? If not, how will emacs know which to open in Emacs, and which in the browser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with a custom link type, as [described here](http://orgmode.org/manual/Adding-hyperlink-types.html).

The following code minimally does this for your case:

```
;; a function to open files in the browser:
(defun my-browse-file (path)
  (browse-url
  (concat "file:" path)))

;; add the new link type
(org-add-link-type "hfile" 'my-browse-file)
```

With this, you can use links in this format:

> [[hfile:///home/tws/scratch][my file]]

I think you need to use the absolute path to your file, I don't think you can use relative paths. At least, not when you pass the path to the browser as `file:///path/to/file`, as is done here. You could alter `my-browse-file` to insert the `///` for you, so your links can skip that bit.